# Reactive Extensions - Stop flow until variable is filled

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, system.reactive

I have the following code. My method has a string return type.

```
public string GetRedemeptionNumber()
{

string _batchNumber = "test";
var _loadBatchName = Observable.ForkJoin(_context.QuerySingleOrDefault(
            _context.GetRedemptionsQuery().Where(x => x.ReceiveBatchName.StartsWith(_batchNumber))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.ReceiveBatchName)
            .Take(1)))
            .Do(u => _redemptionBatch = u.FirstOrDefault())
                               .Select(x => new Unit())
                               .Finally(() =>
                               {
                                       _batchNumber = _redemptionBatch.Name;

                                      //this doesnt work since a return isnt allowed
                                       return _batchNumber;
                                   }
                               });

        _loadBatchName.Subscribe();


        return _batchNumber;
}
```

My issue is this runs through and return my _batchNumber before it is set. so it is returning an empty _batchNumber. Is there a way to stop this from running to the return (outside of my .finally) and wait for the _batchNumber to be filled from within my .finally.

My code clearly doesnt work right now since my .finally does not allow a return in it.

Comment: Can you describe what you actually want to do here? Maybe instead of Finally you want Aggregate?

Comment: the _batchNumber is getting set early in the method..this code runs all the way to the return _batchNumber before I set it in the finally. What i want is for the execution to stop before the return _batchNumber that is at the bottom of method. I am not sure exactly what the Aggregate would do.

Comment: I mean, describe the goal of this code - what is the *scenario*?

Comment: I am basically getting a batchNumber created from a variety of variables - username, date and some other hard coded items. my batchnumber will look like this RCV-evjen-072711 what i will then do after i have this batchNumber is query the database on that number - then with startsWith- in my DB, that batchNumber ends with -1 or -2 etc..I then will increment that last number. so i could end up with a batch number of RCV-gevjen-072711-2. that will be my final batchnumber that i need to return. hope that make sense.

Comment: It would be useful for you to document the return types of `_context.QuerySingleOrDefault` and `_context.GetRedemptionsQuery`

Answer (score 2):

Your code does have a few problems.

First up if you want to block until Rx returns then there isn't much point using Rx. It should be about not blocking. So you should really return `IObservable<string>` and not `string`.

Also, for your query to have `OrderByDescending` you much be using an enumerable and not an observable so somehow your query must turn into an observable.

And `ForkJoin` doesn't seem to do anything for you in this query. Why did you use it?

All of the `Do` & `Finally` operators don't make much sense either.

In any case, I couldn't refactor your code into something that compiles, but I got it close. Start with this and tell me what needs to change.

```
public static IObservable<string> GetRedemeptionNumber()
{
    var _batchNumber = "test";

    var q =
        _context.GetRedemptionsQuery()
        .Where(x => x.ReceiveBatchName.StartsWith(_batchNumber))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ReceiveBatchName)
        .Take(1);

    return (from u in _context.QuerySingleOrDefault(q)
            from z in u
            select z.Name).Take(1);
}
```